# Owl Carousel does not respect Image Styles as set in node display in custom node file

Tags: theming, nodes

I am trying to get owl carousel to respect the image style declared in the manage display setting for the content type. The code I used to output in the node is:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme nav-inside box-shadow-custom mt-xl" data-plugin-options='{"items": 1, "margin": 10, "animateOut": "fadeOut", "autoplay": true, "autoplayTimeout": 3000}'>
            <?php foreach($image as $value):?>
                <div>
                    <img src="<?php print file_create_url($value['uri']);?>" class="img-responsive"  alt="">
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
```

This renders the slides all different sizes and makes it have a background and causes it to look bad. Does anyone know how to in a custom node file make it respect the image style that I have created that cause it to scale and crop the images. Thanks.

Comment: Since you are not rendering the field normally, I don't see anywhere that the image style would be respected. What is the value of `uri`?

Comment: file_create_url() gives you original file URL, what you can do is then run it by image_style_url($style_name, $path) and you will get what you want.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I am so bad at php. cchen, is there any way you can show me what that would look like?

Comment: @tHaKaREe something like src="<?php $original_image_url = file_create_url($value['uri']); $styled_image_url = image_style_url($style_name, $original_image_url); print $styled_image_url;?>", you will have to find a way to get the $style_name value though. Does that make sense?

Comment: @tHaKaREe No worries. $style_name is the machine name of the image style you set in the display settings admin page. I think it should be available somewhere when you run dpm($node or something)... Should be pretty similar to how you get the $value['uri'] value.

Comment: @cchen 
Thanks again for helping. It really doesn't make sense to me as I suck at php. I can usually muddle through but I am stumped by this statement "you will have to find a way to get the $style_name value though"

Comment: @cchen Would this be what I am looking for: [link] https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_style_url/7.x [/link]

Comment: @tHaKaREe yes that’s the function

Comment: @cchen I got it to work with this:     <?php $img_url = $node->field_images['und'][0]['uri'];?>
                        <img src="<?php print image_style_url("property", $img_url); ?>" class="img-responsive"  alt=""> but it only shows 1 image

Comment: @tHaKaREe nice, how many are there in the $image var array?

Comment: @cchen there are anywhere from 10-20 on each node.

Comment: @cchen I should also clarify, It shows that there is the right number of images, but when you slide through the carousel all the images are the first image over and over.

Comment: @tHaKaREe Gotcha, I think this is because you have $node->field_images['und'][0]['uri']; in the code, here we need to use an index instead of saying [0] all the time. Try foreach($array as $key=>$value) instead. $key will be your index.

Comment: @cchen This is all the code associated with my slideshow...Any way you could show me what you meant? I tried no luck    <?php $image = array();
if(!empty($node->field_images['und'])){
    $image = $node->field_images['und'];
}
?> 

 <?php $img_url = $node->field_images[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri'];?> 
                <?php foreach($image as $value):?>
                    <div>
                        

                        <img src="<?php print image_style_url("property", $img_url); ?>" class="img-responsive"  alt="">
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach;?>

Comment: @tHaKaREe I'll probably need a little bit more info to get it to work, care to email me 23cchen@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize my comments:
 1. after getting the images' URLs, you can run them by `image_style_url()` function to get the URLs to the styled images. 
 2. you need to update the `foreach()` function to include an index such as `foreach($image as $key=>$value)`, and use the `$key` index to loop through the image array.